# Pyreverse doesn't detect that the parent class is a Composite... why?

Tags: python, oop, pylint, composite, pyreverse

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 986C-80E1
C:.
    test.py
    __init__.py
    
No subfolders exist
```

`__init__.py` is blank. In `test.py`. I have the following code:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, identifier, name, address):
        self.address = None

class Manager(Employee):
    pass

class Secretary(Employee):
    pass

class Address:
    def __init__(self, street_num, street_name):
        self.street_num = street_num
        self.street_name = street_name
```

The idea here is to implement simple one-to-many composition. That is, all `Employee` subtypes also contain an `Address` instance.

I then run `pyreverse -S -o uml.png .` to generate a UML class diagram and get the following:

[image]

`pyreverse` doesn't recognize that there is a composite-component relationship between `Employee` and `Address`. However, if I refactor `test.py` to the following:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, identifier, name):
        self.address = None

class Manager(Employee):
    pass

class Secretary(Employee):
    pass

class Address:
    def __init__(self, street_num, street_name):
        self.street_num = street_num
        self.street_name = street_name

bob = Manager(1, "Bob")
bob.address =  Address(1, "main ave")
```

I get that `Address` has an association with `Manager`.

[image]

Is this not technically incorrect? The association, as far as I understand, should be with the parent class `Employee`. Why does `pyreverse` consider that `Address` is only a component of `Manager`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pyreverse` detects that you have instantiated `Manager` and this is why it considers `Address` to be part of `Manager`. If you make a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in your constructor, then `pyreverse` should detect the correct relationship between `Employee` and `Address`.

Comment: I suspected type hints might be the way to go. Do you mind providing an example of my first version of `test.py` where it actually works? Thanks.

Comment: @user32882 I would be glad to do it, but I'm not a Python programmer. Maybe something like `def __init__(self, identifier, name, address: Address):` would help you, but I'm not sure whether this is syntactically correct. I know that type hint is the solution, but I'm not experienced with Python.

Comment: Hi @Lajos. Thanks. In that case I'll hold off accepting the answer until I actually try it with type hints and make sure it works. If anyone else can provide a working example in the meantime I'd be curious to see what it looks like.

Comment: @user32882 sure thing. Please do try this and let me know about the results.